# What is the process of building/installing a service?

Tags: c#

I am creating a simple service in VS2008 C#

How do I install it on my computer so that it runs when I start my machine?

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio supports Windows Services as a type of application. I believe the template for this only exists in the Professional Edition. However, you can build a service by creating a ServiceProcess Installer and using InstallUtil.

You can find more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984464%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

When you create a New Project, select the type of project Windows Service. Depending on the version of Visual Studio, you may have to browse to the Windows templates section to find it.

Comment: i know that. how do i install it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Visual Studio Command prompt.

1. Open the visual studio command prompt (where this is depends on a number of things, see [this page for info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229859.aspx). When you find it, it's useful to add it as an external tool in your tools menu in visual studio).
2. Navigate to the folder containing the exe for your service
3. Run `installutil <yourexe>` where  is the name of the executable file.
4. If you specified the service to run as a specific user, it will now prompt you to enter that user's credentials.

Depending on settings, you may need to go into services (start > run> services.msc) and set it to start automatically on boot.

You can then uninstall using `installutil /u <yourexe>` if you ever need to, using pretty much the same process.

Comment: why would i have a DLL? i dont have DLL

Comment: @JOE SKEET sorry, that was meant to say exe. My bad, will fix it.

Comment: from which dir should i run installutil?

Comment: Well, if you build your service in release mode, it'll be the bin/release dir inside your project directory. Otherwise bin/debug. Basically it's the directory that contains your service's exe.